# Eagle all grounds connecting together

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I just started to use EAGLE (9.6.2 free version). I am watching someone. When he makes the ground connection, his board's ground doesn't connect with wire but my GNDs are connecting together. Is it a problem? If it is how can I solve that? I mean yellow wire is going over pins. Are pins involving GND?

[image]

[image]

Comment: With a mouse right-click you can rotate symbols (like gnd) as you place them. This will make your layout prettier.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: By the way, the ESP32 is not very happy if you don't add some external decoupling caps. If you start all the radios (WiFi and BT) at the same time, it may reset. Because you are doing the PCB, please add some big ceramics caps (22uF) close to the VCC pins of the ESP. Just in case. It costs nothing to not mount them at the end. But it's very annoying to realize afterward that you need them and you haven't planed any spare footprint for them.... just a quick tips...

Comment: @Blup1980 I will use esp01 like this https://tr.aliexpress.com/item/32341788594.html . Raspberry pi pico provide 3.3 GPIO pin so I don't need to add resistor but I heard caps first time. You are saying I need to add 2 Caps on Esp01's vcc pin right ?

Comment: Yes, it's better to add additional capacitors between the VCC pin of the ESP and GND. If your tests shows that you don't need them, don't solder them. The PCB won't become more expensive if you anticipate a footprint for theses caps. (ceramic, not electrolytic !)

Comment: You are planning to power the ESP through a GPIO of the Raspberry pi pico ?

Comment: @Blup1980 I actually have no idea how to power Esp01. In breadboard I am using raspberry pi pico's 5V to Esp01's CH PD- and 3.3V (I know I need to use pico's 3.3V but Pico isn't provide current) and rx ,tx,gnd. I also need power for HX711 and 2 Servo's. As I said I am noob I didn't design before and I don't have anyone to ask .

Comment: I see. What I recommend is to do some kind of design. Only focus on the schematics, the PCB will come later. Post it here, in another question asking for a review. Don't forget to specify that you are a beginner, otherwise you will get comments that will be irrelevant to your level. And some people will be happy to correct it. Then you fix all the issues and submit your new design and iterate.

Comment: @Blup1980 okay I will post it and ask for advice. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the problem here? Same Nets (Same Name) get connected together. If you want to split grounds, use diffrent symbols for each rail.

Comment: In board design yellow line goes over the pins , I though that is the problem (isn't it ?). When he do that his yellow line 's are not connecting with yellow line.

Comment: You see: These so called airwires are the connections still to be routed in the layout. Just click on one. It will highlight all the pads (gnd in this case) that need to be connected together - all the others are not affected.

Comment: When i click Show on schematic and then Esp's GND's green line ,only GND's are shining. Okay I get it. In board even yellow line goes over pins it doesn't mean it involves pins. Right ?

Comment: correct! You got it. Type 'show gnd' in the command line in board view. Or click on the 'route' symbol and then click on an airwire.

Comment: Thank you @ElectronicsStudent

Comment: your welcome @mrneedshelpalot - please upvote

Comment: @ElectronicStudent I can't I don't have 15 reputation.